# is "*html" a valid selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

As in

```
*html .tblCol5 div.removeColumn{width:58px}
```

I'm getting an error on this in FF Error Console. I've found the solution [CSS Star Selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/workaroundsfilters#workaroundsfilters__sect_starhtmlselector).  The correct syntax is `* html` (insert a space between " * " and `html`).  Even though I didn't post the question, I didn't see one similar to it so thought it was worth posting for informational purposes (if that is allowed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because * is a selector itself, it means: 'everything', while *html has no meaning..

Comment: Found another use for "star" hack.  <a href="http://www.impressivewebs.com/center-multiple-divs/">Star Hack for IE6-7</a> it is being used **without** the space at the beginning of of each line to hide those rules from all browsers except IE6/7.  So it doesn't just represent a "selector".

Comment: P.S. I don't get how to use the "link" formatting on stackoverflow in these comment boxes.  I read the "learn more..." but I still don't get it.

Comment: just paste the link, SO will handle it by itself. You don't need to add a space at the beginning of the line, the space must be placed between * and html. By the way, you should avoid abusing this kind of tricks unless you really need them. This is probably an IE bug, since the HTML tag is always the root, and therefore makes this semantic a bit odd.. The style is hidden by the star selector because there is no element which can be the parent of the HTML element.

Comment: @Chris22: HTML anchor links don't work in comments. Kinda odd if you ask me. You can still use [Markdown syntax](...) to create links, though.